# Deploying to bintray from Maven fails

Tags: java, maven, deployment, maven-release-plugin, bintray

I've set up the maven build for a Java project according to [Publishing releases using Github, Bintray and maven-release-plugin](http://veithen.github.io/2013/05/26/github-bintray-maven-release-plugin.html) , a blog post by Andreas Veithen.

My `pom` version is 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT, and I've created the respective version `1.0.2` in my bintray package. I perform `mvn -Prelease clean install`, no problems. I perform `mvn release:prepare`, no problems. But when I perform `mvn release:perform`, the build breaks with the error message below.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy 
(default-deploy) on project [PROJECT]: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not 
transfer artifact my.project:test:jar:1.0.2-20140408.154954-1 from/to bintray-
user-maven-package (https://api.bintray.com/maven/user/maven/package): Failed to 
transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/user/maven/package/my/project/test/
1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/test-1.0.2-20140408.154954-1.jar. Return code is: 400, 
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request. -> [Help 1]
```

I'm noticing that the release plugin is trying to upload the **SNAPSHOT**, and of course this should have no place on bintray... I'd have thought that it would try to deploy **1.0.2**? How can I convince maven to upload the correct artifact, or is there anything wrong with my set up?

Below are the parts of the POM that I think are relevant, the complete POM is at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3vd6Axx0).

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>my.tool</groupId>
<artifactId>util</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/user/package.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:user/package.git</developerConnection>
  <url>https://github.com/user/package</url>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>bintray-user-maven-package</id>
    <name>user-maven-package</name>
    <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/user/maven/package</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-javadocs</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
 <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>
           <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
           </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
            <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <header>${basedir}/src/etc/header.txt</header>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/main/java/**</include>
                    <include>src/test/java/**</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <configuration>
            <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to release 1.0.2 and not 1.0.1? Because I'd expect Maven to try and deploy 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT after the release of 1.0.1.

Comment: @JBaruch: Sorry, I've made a number of hard resets and deleted tags after a couple of failed releases. I've changed the POM version to `1.0.2-SNAPSHOT` again...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to post your pom in order to understand what's wrong with your maven release plugin configuration.

Also consider this:
You can use oss.jfrog.org to [host your snapshots](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425) and convert to releases automatically during the push to Bintray.

- Disadvantage - for open-source projects that linked to jcenter only
- Advantage - [everything else](http://youtu.be/8TMqCkC_0KA) :) Free Artifactory instance for development process, integration with any CI server (hosted or cloud), transparent release to Bintray with a single rest API call.

Comment: Thanks. Added relevant POM excerpts to the question and put the whole thing up at pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

During the maven `mvn release:perform` step, the file should be transfered to:

```
https://api.bintray.com/maven/user/maven/package/my/project/test/1.0.2
```

And not to:

```
https://api.bintray.com/maven/user/maven/package/my/project/test/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

This is why Bintray correcly returns:

```
Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
```

Upgrading maven-release-plugin from (my) v2.2.2 to currently latest v2.5 fixed it for me. After the upgrade, the `mvn release:prepare` step behave differently.

---

### Return code is: 401

As mentionned by @vorburger in the comment, if (using maven-deploy-plugin:2.7) Bintray returns:

```
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

Then that 'just' means that you have no or a wrong username and password for the `<server>` in the `settings.xml`:

```
<server>
  <id>{matching-id}</id>
  <username>{bintray-user}</username>
  <password>{bintray-api-key}</password>
</server>
```

The `matching-id` value should be the same than the one defined in the `pom.xml` file (in the `<distributionManagement>` > `<repository>` section).

The `bintray-api-key` value can be generated in the [API Key section of the Bintray profile settings](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/interacting/interacting_editingyouruserprofile.html#anchorAPIKEY).

---

### Do not use `mvn deploy` for to perform a release

By mistake I originally tried `mvn deploy` (which attempted to push a `*-SNAPSHOT`) instead of `mvn release:prepare` + `mvn release:perform` (which correctly creates and pushes a release).

Comment: PS: If instead of "Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request." you hit a "Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized." from https://api.bintray.com/maven/... (using maven-deploy-plugin:2.7), then that 'just' means that you have no or a wrong username and password for the <server> (with matching <id> ...) in the settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Downgrading the maven-release-plugin to version 2.4 solved the issue for me.